# A javascript function to format javascript code

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know of a javascript library that will take a chunk of javascript source and format it according to some set of rules. I can of course do it in my editor but I would like to be able to automate it as part of a build process.

Comment: Your build process is in Javascript? What?

Comment: So, why do you need this?  I guess you could try "Counting" parenthesis and curly braces, but... honestly, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in js, but maybe it could help:

- http://jsbeautifier.org/

(online and python version)

Comment: There is a JS Version and actually I found it some time ago, Thanks :)